# Integrating $\sin (xt)$

Tags: integration

Can someone please give me the mathematical reasoning behind this fact:

$$ \displaystyle \int \sin (x) \space dx = - \cos(x) + C$$

but

$$ \displaystyle \int \sin (xt) \space dx = - \dfrac {\cos (tx)}{t} + C$$

Comment: Differentiate the RHS.

Comment: With respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a $u$ substitution.  Note that we are considering $t$ to be a constant.  Let $u=xt, du=t\; dx$ then $$\int \sin(xt) dx=\int \sin (u) \frac 1t du=-\frac{\cos(u)}t+C=-\frac{\cos(tx)}t+C$$